# Razor/cshtml debug variables no longer showing values when I hover?

Tags: visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2017

Previously if I set a breakpoint in a cshtml file I could hover over a variable and Visual Studio would tell me the value.

Now when I hover a variable in cshtml, it just tells me the type... And I have to individually Shift+F9 (quickwatch) on every variable I want to see the value of.

How do I get back the hover showing the value?

Is the a change in a recent Visual Studio update? I'm using 15.7.3

I've already tried resetting to default settings, and still get the issue

Comment: related question https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/249225/razor-debugging-doesnt-show-variable-value-on-hove.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in Visual Studio Community

Fixed in Visual Studio Community 15.7.5

See first item in release notes:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#top-issues-fixed-in-1575